# how to stretch columns in JTable by content?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I try do it with this code:

```
class MyTable extends JTable {

@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row,
        int column) {
    Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    int rendererWidth = component.getPreferredSize().width;
    TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    tableColumn
            .setPreferredWidth(Math.max(rendererWidth
                    + getIntercellSpacing().width,
                    tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));
    return component;
}
```

It worked good until I added this code:

```
setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Now it doesn't work. But I need in this line of code. Is it possible to solve my problem?

**UPD:** After `setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` columns don't stretched by content. It looks like that:[image: that:]:

It has a lot of differnces with this question: [How can I get the correct JTable width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997328/how-can-i-get-the-correct-jtable-width). In this question I want to understand how can I get table width. And now I want to stetch columns in JTable by content. Look at the picture. the text does not fit in the column. I want to understand how to solve it.

Comment: Александр Елизаров What happens after setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF) ?

Comment: @Leet-Falcon, I edit my question to demonstate what happens after setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF)